# Longest sequences in a list (including overlapping)?

Tags: c#, .net, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Let's say we have a list of Node objects with a Value property.
Is there a time-efficient algorithm to link Node pairs of the same Value within the longest repeated Node-range(s) only?

Overlapping is allowed so is multiple longest node-pair spans if they have the same length.

The Value property is irreducible to char and therefore the "*longest repeated substring*" algorithm is not the answer.

**Example:**

```
INPUT:
Node Values =
{ AA, BB, CC, DD, AA, BB, CC, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF, EE, FF } // Values
  00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18   // indices

OUTPUT:
Edges (from_node_index, to_node_index) =
{
  (00-07, 01-08, 02-09, 03-10),
  (08-12, 09-13, 10-14, 11-15),
  (15-17, 16-18)
}
```

Here is my naive attempt using C# which I think runs in O(n^2 log n) time complexity.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_nodes.Count - 1; i++)
{
    int first_j = -1;
    int range = 0;  // maximum number of repeated nodes in node range
    int k = 0;      // current number of repeated nodes in node range

    for (int j = i + 1; j < m_nodes.Count; j++)
    {
        if (m_nodes[i].Value == m_nodes[j].Value)
        {
            k = 0;
            do
            {
                k++;
                if ((j + k) == m_nodes.Count) break;
            } while (m_nodes[i + k].Value == m_nodes[j + k].Value);

            if (k > range)
            {
                range = k;

                first_j = j;
                j += range; // skip repeating nodes
            }
        }
    }

    if (range > 0)
    {
        if (first_j > i)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < range; x++)
            {
                if (first_j >= 0)
                {
                    Edge edge = new Edge();
                    if (edge != null)
                    {
                        edge.Id = ++count;
                        edge.Source = m_nodes[i + x];
                        edge.Target = m_nodes[first_j + x];
                        edge.Label = m_nodes[first_j + x].Text + " = " + m_nodes[first_j + x].Value.ToString();
                        edge.Range = range;
                        edge.NumberInRange = x + 1;
                        m_edges.Add(edge);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel Dynamic Programming might be the answer but I am not familiar with that.

Here is the full source code: https://yadi.sk/d/aDdN9slB0H7BQA

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Latest code at http://QuranCode.com